# Get Mapbox tile-reduce up and running

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, vector-tiles, node-js, tile-reduce

I'm new to [Mapbox tile-reduce library](https://github.com/mapbox/tile-reduce). I would like to process OSM tiles for Portugal.

I've download the [mbtiles from Portugal](http://osmlab.github.io/osm-qa-tiles/country.html).
I've installed `tile-reduce` with:

```
npm ini
npm install @mapbox/tile-reduce
```

I've downloaded the `tile-reduce/examples/count/` example.
My `index.js` is:

```
'use strict';
var tileReduce = require('@mapbox/tile-reduce');
var path = require('path');
var numFeatures = 0;
tileReduce({
    zoom: 12,
    map: path.join(__dirname, '/count.js'),
    sources: [{name: 'portugal', mbtiles: path.join(__dirname, 'portugal.mbtiles'), raw: true}]
})
.on('reduce', function (num) {
    numFeatures += num;
})
.on('end', function () {
    console.log('Features total: %d', numFeatures);
});
```

My `count.js` is:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(data, tile, writeData, done) {
  var count = 0;
  if (data.portugal.roads) count += data.portugal.roads.length;
  if (data.portugal.buildings) count += data.portugal.buildings.length;
  done(null, count);
};
```

I was expecting to have the number of roads and buildings on the output, but the result is 0 features.

```
jgr@dusseldorf:/media/bonn/mapbox$ node index.js
Starting up 8 workers... Job started.
Processing tile coords from "portugal" source.
1876 tiles processed in 1s.
Features total: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tile-reduce example](https://github.com/mapbox/tile-reduce/tree/master/examples/count) does not work with [OSM QA TILES COUNTRY EXTRACTS](http://osmlab.github.io/osm-qa-tiles/country.html). The tile content is different.

To count roads and buildings using tiles from country extracts, we need to iterate over all features in the tile.

The following `count.js` works:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (data, tile, writeData, done) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.portugal.osm.length; i++) {
        var feature = data.portugal.osm.feature(i);
        if (feature.properties.highway || feature.properties.building) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    done(null, count);
};
```

On the output we can see the number of roads and buildings:

```
jgr@dusseldorf:/media/bonn/mapbox$ node index.js
Starting up 8 workers... Job started.
Processing tile coords from "portugal" source.
1876 tiles processed in 2s.
Features total: 1389373
```